# How to creat a progress bar in Dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'd like to create a progress bar after clicking a button.
For example, it goes from 0%, 20%, 40%, 60, 80%, 100% in 5 seconds.
Then the bar disappears.
How do I do this?
I see a tutorial that use dcc.interval, but the interval just automatically increase. I cannot control the start of the interval with a button.

Comment: did you ever checked the progress-bar in dash-bootstrap-components site? https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/progress/

Comment: I have checked it before I ask the question.

Comment: The site only talks about the frontend. The hard part is about the communication